# Robot Framework : Is there any way using which we can execute test cases (same test cases/test suit) on multiple andriod devices at once?

Tags: robotframework

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mc2He.png)Once the app is launched on multiple android devices. How can we execute same test cases on multiple mobile devices at once? As I am having a bunch of test cases to execute on multiple android devices. I am trying to use For Loop by passing udid OR Appium Server name in Test cases,but it's not working.It executes test case on a single device only.Is there any way using which we can execute test cases (same test cases/test suit) on multiple Android devices at once?

Answer (score 1):

You could use https://github.com/mkorpela/pabot with --argumentfile[NUMBER] options.

Answer (score 1):

What you basically want to do is **Parallel execution** of your tests. There are many tools available to achieve this with ease and much coverage (vast number of devices and flavors) like SeeTest Cloud, Xamarin Test Cloud, AWS Device Farm, Perfecto etc

However if you want to achieve using Appium and TestNG it is still possible. Below are high level steps:

1. Launch multiple instances of Appium server, by using different
   address, port, callbackPort, and BootstrapPort as part of node
   command.
2. Get the UUID of the devices and pass it in TestNG xml
3. Run the xml as suite.

Below is the link with exact commands and steps:
http://toolsqa.com/mobile-automation/appium/appium-parallel-execution-using-testng/

Comment: Thanks.. i dont want to use Appium with TestNG. I am using Robot Framwork with Appium..

Comment: For Robot framework also steps are pretty much same. You have to create multiple instances of Appium. Only the execution part changes. Here is the link for more info: http://testnblog.com/executing-robot-test-cases-in-parallel-on-2-android-devices-through-appium/

Comment: Your link is not working.. yes i am having multiple instances of Appium running already with diff port and host also.. but still its not working for me..

Comment: Oh ok. Then you are already half way through. But Strange the same link is working for me. Posting it again:  http://testnblog.com/executing-robot-test-cases-in-parallel-on-2-android-devices-through-appium/

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes i can access the given link. i have started my Appium instance manually and then using  keyword i launched app on both the devices.But when i use IF statement OR For loop for my below test case then its working on only one device which is last accessed.

Comment: *******Keywords*****       Enter URL
    : FOR    ${APPIUM_SERVER1}    ${deviceName}    ${udid}    IN    http://localhost:4723/wd/hub    adb devices
    ...    emulator-5556
    \    Wait Until Page Contains Element    xpath=//android.widget.EditText    timeout=60
    \    Click Element    xpath=//android.widget.EditText[@text='Please enter URL']
    \    Input Text    xpath=//android.widget.EditText[@text='Please enter URL']    http://xxx.xx.xx.xx:9000
    \    Click Element    xpath=//android.widget.Button[@text = 'OK']

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like following as solution to your problem. As I had said earlier in my answer, you can save the drivers in a dictionary `&{drivers}` and use it in your loop to do repetitive actions on all your devices.

```
*** Settings ***
Library           AppiumLibrary
Library          Collections
Library          Process

*** Variables ***
${APPIUM_SERVER1}    http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub
${APPIUM_SERVER2}    http://127.0.0.1:4750/wd/hub
${udid_device1}    udid of device 1
${udid_device2}    udid of device 2

*** Keywords ***
setup and open android phone A
    &{drivers}=    Create Dictionary
    ${androiddriver1}=    Open Application    ${APPIUM_SERVER1}    platformName=android    platformVersion=7.0    deviceName=android   udid=${udid_device1}    automationName=uiautomator2
    ...    appPackage=com.android.contacts    newCommandTimeout=2500    appActivity=com.android.contacts.activities.PeopleActivity
    Set To Dictionary    ${drivers}    ${udid_device1}=${androiddriver1}
    Set suite variable    ${drivers}


setup and open android phone B
    ${androiddriver2}=    Open Application    ${APPIUM_SERVER2}    platformName=android    platformVersion=7.0    deviceName=android    udid=${udid_device2}    automationName=uiautomator2
    ...    appPackage=com.htc.contacts   newCommandTimeout=2500    noReset=True    appActivity=com.htc.contacts.BrowseLayerCarouselActivity
    Set To Dictionary    ${drivers}    ${udid_device2}=${androiddriver2}
    Set suite variable    ${drivers}
    Log Dictionary    ${drivers}

Open URL
    :FOR    ${key}    IN    @{drivers.keys()}
    \    ${value}=    Get From Dictionary    ${drivers}    ${key}
    \    Log    ${key}, ${value}
    \    repetitive actions here
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried above code but still its not executing my test case on both devices. Application launch on both device but next test case (Open URL) gets executed on only last device (2nd device which is accessed for Open Application. I try using different variable as well but still its giving me same issue.

Comment: that is another question, you need to use a data structure like dictionary to store values related to phones in it and call them in further actions using ${${key}.variablename} format.

Comment: Thanks..Sory i am new to Robot so dont know much ...need to check that..anyway the issue is ..its just not switching the connection to other device:

Comment: Starting test: TEST16thJan.StartApp.Enter URL for Login
20180123 16:20:03.500 :  INFO : ${value} = 1
20180123 16:20:03.502 :  INFO : ${value} = 2
20180123 16:20:03.503 :  INFO : [u'emulator-5554'], [u'emulator-5556']

Comment: @Pooja did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

you can save sessions from `open application` in a dictionary and use them in a loop to do some actions on every phone.
Please edit your question with code for further help.

Comment: *******Keywords***** Enter URL : FOR ${APPIUM_SERVER1} ${deviceName} ${udid} IN localhost:4723/wd/hub adb devices ... emulator-5556 \ Wait Until Page Contains Element xpath=//android.widget.EditText timeout=60 \ Click Element xpath=//android.widget.EditText[@text='Please enter URL'] \ Input Text xpath=//android.widget.EditText[@text='Please enter URL'] xxx.xx.xx.xx:9000 \ Click Element xpath=//android.widget.Button[@text = 'OK'] –

Comment: The above keyword not running on both device.It runs on only device which last accessed.How i use the For Loop so that my "ENTER URL" test case executed on both the device one after other ?

Comment: Paste ur code in question with proper formatting,then only we can help!!